# Please Help AttributeError: Final argument must be a dict of transaction parameters that includes a `from` field specifying the address to deploy from

Tags: solidity, transactions, python, brownie

I get this error when I try run my brownie `deploy_lottery.py scripts --- network rinkeby`. Do anyone have an idea on how to solve this? Thanks.

[image]

Here's the script:

```
from scripts.helpful_script import get_account, get_contract, fund_with_link
from brownie import Lottery, network, config
import time
import os



def deploy_lottery():
    account = get_account()
    lottery = Lottery.deploy(
        get_contract("eth_usd_price_feed").address,
        get_contract("vrf_Coordinator").address,
        get_contract("link_token").address,
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["fee"],
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["keyhash"],
        {"from": account},
        publish_source=config["networks"][network.show_active()].get("verify", False),
   )
    print("Deployed lottery!")
    return lottery

def start_lottery():
    account = get_account()
    lottery = Lottery[-1]
    starting_tx = lottery.startLottery({"from": account})
    starting_tx.wait(1)
    print("The lottery is started!")


def enter_lottery():
    account = get_account()
    lottery = Lottery[-1]
    value = lottery.getEntranceFee() + 100000000
    tx = lottery.enter({"from": account, "value": value})
    tx.wait(1)
    print("You entered the lottery!")
```

When I use brownie run scripts `deploy_lotterry.py -- network rinkeby` i get this error :

```
Running 'scripts/deploy_lottery.py::main'...
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 110, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "./scripts/deploy_lottery.py", line 51, in main
    deploy_lottery()
  File "./scripts/deploy_lottery.py", line 10, in deploy_lottery
    lottery = Lottery.deploy(
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 544, in __call__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Final argument must be a dict of transaction parameters that includes a `from` field specifying the address to deploy from
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in Lottery.deploy() part. Check it should be like this `Lottery.deploy({"from": account})`